# Create an array inside a class with php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a class and I need to build an array. I usually can do that with a query and looping that but I am not sure how to do that with a class.

Do I create the array before hand and turn it into a string?

Here is my [code sample](http://pastebin.com/aux1pa2K)

```
/** My Setting class **/

if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_my_setting' ) ) {

class WC_my_setting {

public function __construct() {

    // Init settings
    $this->settings = array(
        array(
          'name' => __( 'My Setting', 'woocommerce-my-setting' ),
          'type' => 'title',
          'id' => 'wc_my_setting_options'
        ),
        array(
              'name'          => __( 'Name', 'woocommerce-my-setting' ),                                            
              'id'            => 'wc_my_setting_category',
              'type'          => 'multiselect',
                  //I want to have this->settings[options] populated with the array that the $category_options makes.
              'options'       => $category_options
                  ),
              )
          ),
        array( 'type' => 'sectionend', 'id' => 'woocommerce-my-setting' ),
    );


    // Default options
    add_option( 'wc_my_setting_category', '' );


    // Admin
    add_action( 'woocommerce_settings_image_options_after', array( $this, 'admin_settings' ), 20 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_catalog', array( $this, 'save_admin_settings' ) );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_products', array( $this, 'save_admin_settings' ) );

}
```

I can the code below on page templates just fine and I can output the array fine but I cannot get this working in the class in the admin area:

```
$categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=0' );
$category_options = array();

    if ( $categories ) {
      foreach ( $categories as $cat ) {
      $category_options[ $cat->slug ] = $cat->name;
      }
    }
// print_r($category_options);
```

How do I get the above loop in my class so the `$category_options` is placed in the `$this->settings[options]`

Comment: Npt sure what you are asking

Comment: Sorry gang, I might be in over my head on this one. I'll try to explain a bit more. If you see the above comments in the code the "my-category-slug" and its value of "My Category Name" are taxonomies inserted in woocommerce in another area of the plug-in. I am trying to bring them in here.I can hard-code the array but that is not the best way if the categories change later. Normally I can just create a loop (like at the end of my post) to get the ID's and create the object. but I dont know how I would do that inside of this situation.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
     class Test
    {
        var $TestArray = array();

        function Test($inputArray)
        {
            $this->setTestArray($inputArray);
            $this->Display();
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: I'm still not following this. I updated my pastebin link above to included more code. to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

class nameClass
{
    public $settings = array();

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->settings = array('id' => '10','name' => 'Peter');
}
```

}

$objSettings = new nameClass();

var_dump($objSettings->settings);

var_dump($objSettings->settings);

can you get it?

Comment: Thanks @THT14 but I dont think that is what I am trying to get at. I am trying to populate 'options' key with a value that is an array. I can manually add the key=>value in the array but want to dynamically populate it with the taxonomy of product categories set in woocommerce. I that I can assign it as `'options' => $my_string,` But then how do I get the $my_string value populated with the array of product categories?

Comment: have you the array with the correct options that you want to populate inside $this->settings[0]['options'] ?

Comment: Not yet. So far I am getting errors with the taxonomy.`WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_taxonomy] => Array ( [0] => Invalid taxonomy ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )` is not finding `get_terms('product_cat')` which is what it is supposed to find.

Comment: I can get the array I want now. but not in the admin area. I have added it to my original post.

Comment: Ken, i was looking for and i found an answear that explained how to get all slugs from each category, give a look the comment from 'keesiemeijer' in this link:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/echo-all-category-slugs-inside-a-foreach

with this foreach you can build an array and after put it inside the $this->settings[0]['options'].

Comment: Yup that is similar to what I am using. I have the code to get the array. Its in my original post. I just dont know how to use it in a class and then populate the $this->settings[options]

Comment: well, you can pass a parameter $category in construct method, before you instance the class WC_my_setting in your code, u can put this way, i don't know if it's the way you want, but, take a look:

one page from your wordpress...

$categories = get_the_category();

$objSettings = new WC_my_setting($categories);

and inside your construct code you can manipulate the $categories,

foreach ($categories as $category) {
echo $category->cat_name;
// echo $category->slug;
}

???